# Windows Backup Tool only copies folder structure

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-vista

I used the Windows Backup Tool to backup Windows Vista files onto an HDD and then used the Windows 10 version of the tool to restore them. For some reason, only the folder structure was copied - my Documents has all the folders the older computer had but none of the files. The only files that were copied are Program Files, which the backup tool explicitly and correctly states shouldn't be copied since they're not useful to the new machine. Are all these problems just because I went directly from Vista to 10?

EDIT: I don't need help backing up the files. I just want to know why an official program does exactly the opposite of what it says, since jumping all the way from Vista to 10 doesn't seem like it would cause it.

Comment: If you upgraded to the latest version of windows 10 (v1809) you may be suffering from the bug where OneDrive deletes all files from the My Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Backup Tool is on the way out in Windows 10, mainly because it is
of a very low quality. But it is not the tool for your purpose.

Copying all Windows files from Vista to Windows 10 will just destroy it.
You should be more selective.
You should copy only the folders where you have your personal data.

Backup is not recommended, since its format may change between Windows versions.
Just copy the folder manually to the backup disk.

I can't know what are your personal folders, but you should check at least
the folder `C:\Users\username\Documents`.

Application data may be found in the folder
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming`,
but in most cases it's better to re-install and re-setup the applications
rather than copy data created in a much older Windows version.

Comment: The Windows Vista backup tool says it doesn't backup program files and only backs up folders you select - backing up Documents and then restoring it the same place is relatively safe. I could easily just put the documents folder itself on the HDD, I'm more curious as to why the backup tool does exactly the opposite of what it says it will.

Comment: It's just plainly badly programmed, which is why Microsoft is phasing it out in Windows 10, leaving this task to third-party products.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would take a look at some free tools that can handle your requests like Freefilesync and duplicat. Both are free and open-source